# why "productname" not supported when i add productimage code and " NULL not allowed for column "PRODUCTNAME"; SQL statement:"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

```
   i am not add any null in "productName" but error   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "PRODUCTNAME"; SQL statement
```

**my error null not allowed productname so how can i solve this problem HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "PRODUCTNAME"; SQL statement:**

```
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502

 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions NULL not allowed for column "PRODUCTNAME"; SQL statement
```

### **This is full error:**

```
   type: Exception report

        message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "PRODUCTNAME"; SQL statement:

        description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

        exception

        org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "PRODUCTNAME"; SQL statement:
        insert into Product (productId, productCategory, productCondition, productDescription, productManufacturer, productName, productPrice, productStatus, unitInStock) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-196]
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        root cause

        org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "PRODUCTNAME"; SQL statement:
        insert into Product (productId, productCategory, productCondition, productDescription, productManufacturer, productName, productPrice, productStatus, unitInStock) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-196]
            org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:128)
            org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
            com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
            org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
            org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:55)
            org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2757)
            org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3268)
            org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:78)
            org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:304)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
            org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:615)
            org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:608)
            org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:604)
            com.emusicstore.dao.impl.ProductDaoImpl.addProduct(ProductDaoImpl.java:25)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)`enter code here`
            org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
            org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
            org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
            org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
            org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
            org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
            org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
            com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.addProduct(Unknown Source)
            com.emusicstore.controller.HomeController.addProductPost(HomeController.java:84)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
            org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        root cause

        org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column "PRODUCTNAME"; SQL statement:
        insert into Product (productId, productCategory, productCondition, productDescription, productManufacturer, productName, productPrice, productStatus, unitInStock) values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-196]
            at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
            at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
            at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
            at org.h2.table.Column.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Column.java:345)
            at org.h2.table.Table.validateConvertUpdateSequence(Table.java:797)
            at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:151)
            at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:114)
            at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:101)
            at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:260)
            at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:354)
            at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:158)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

            org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:629)
            org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeUpdate(CommandRemote.java:209)
            org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:164)
            org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:150)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
            org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
            com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
            org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
            org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:55)
            org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2757)
            org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3268)
            org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:78)
            org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:304)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
            org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
            org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:615)
            org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:608)
            org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:604)
            com.emusicstore.dao.impl.ProductDaoImpl.addProduct(ProductDaoImpl.java:25)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
            org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
            org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
            org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
            org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
            org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
            org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
            org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
            com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.addProduct(Unknown Source)
            com.emusicstore.controller.HomeController.addProductPost(HomeController.java:84)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
            org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
            org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
            org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.28 logs.
```

### my add product page:

this is add productpage code

```
    <%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
    <%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp"%>


    <div class="container-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Add Product</h1>
                <p class="lead">Fill the below information to a  product: </p>
            </div>


          <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/productInventory/addProduct"  method="post"  commandName="product" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <form:input path="productName" id="name" class="form-Control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category">Category</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCategory" id="category" value="instrument"/>Instrument</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCategory" id="category" value="record"/>Record</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCategory" id="category" value="accessory"/>Accessory</label>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description</label>
                <form:textarea path="productDescription" id="description" class="form-Control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="price">Price</label>
                <form:input path="productPrice" id="price" class="form-Control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="condition">Condition</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCondition" id="condition" value="new"/>New</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCondition" id="condition" value="used"/>Used</label>

            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="status">Status</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productStatus" id="status" value="active"/>Active</label>
                <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productStatus" id="status" value="inactive"/>Inactive</label>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="unitInstock">Unit In stock</label>
                <form:input path="unitInStock" id="unitInstock" class="form-Control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer</label>
                <form:input path="productManufacturer" id="manufacturer" class="form-Control"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="productImage">Upload Picture</label>
                <form:input id="productImage" path="productImage" type="file" class="form:input-large"/>

            </div>

            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success">
            <a href="<c:url value="/admin/productInventory"/> " class="btn btn-default">Cancle</a>



            </form:form>
    <%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp"%>
```

### my controller maping:

this is productimage code

```
    //productimage code
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/productInventory/addProduct" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addProductPost(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product, HttpServletRequest request){

            productDao.addProduct(product);

            MultipartFile productImage = product.getProductImage();
            String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
            path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "\\WEB-INF\\resources\\images\\"+product.getProductId()+".png");

            if (productImage !=null && !productImage.isEmpty())
            {
                try{
                    productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new RuntimeException("Product image saving failed",e);

                }
            }

            return "redirect:/admin/productInventory";

        }
   productimage//
```

### my model Product.java

```
    this is add our product column

    package com.emusicstore.model;

    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

    import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity

    public class Product {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

        private String productId;
        private String productName;
        private String productCategory;
        private String productDescription;
        private double productPrice;
        private String productCondition;
        private String productStatus;
        private int unitInStock;
        private String productManufacturer;

        @Transient//automatic create productImage in database
        private MultipartFile productImage;

        public String getProductId() {
            return productId;
        }

        public void setProductId(String productId) {
            this.productId = productId;
        }



        public String getProductName() {
            return productName;
        }

        public void setProductName(String productName) {
            this.productName = productName;
        }

        public String getProductCategory() {
            return productCategory;
        }

        public void setProductCategory(String productCategory) {
            this.productCategory = productCategory;
        }

        public String getProductDescription() {
            return productDescription;
        }

        public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
            this.productDescription = productDescription;
        }

        public double getProductPrice() {
            return productPrice;
        }

        public void setProductPrice(double productPrice) {
            this.productPrice = productPrice;
        }

        public String getProductCondition() {
            return productCondition;
        }

        public void setProductCondition(String productCondition) {
            this.productCondition = productCondition;
        }

        public String getProductStatus() {
            return productStatus;
        }

        public void setProductStatus(String productStatus) {
            this.productStatus = productStatus;
        }

        public int getUnitInStock() {
            return unitInStock;
        }

        public void setUnitInStock(int unitInStock) {
            this.unitInStock = unitInStock;
        }

        public String getProductManufacturer() {
            return productManufacturer;
        }

        public void setProductManufacturer(String productManufacturer) {
            this.productManufacturer = productManufacturer;
        }


        public MultipartFile getProductImage() {
            return productImage;
        }

        public void setProductImage(MultipartFile productImage) {
            this.productImage = productImage;
        }
    }
```

### my productdaoimpl:

```
    package com.emusicstore.dao.impl;

    import com.emusicstore.dao.ProductDao;
    import com.emusicstore.model.Product;
    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import java.util.List;


    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {


        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public void addProduct(Product product){
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.saveOrUpdate(product);
            session.flush();
        }

        public Product getProductById(String id){
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class,id);
            session.flush();
            return product;
        }

        public List<Product> getAllProducts(){
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from Product");
            List<Product> products= query.list();
            session.flush();

            return products;
        }

        public void deleteProduct(String id){
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.delete(getProductById(id));
            session.flush();


        }
    }

pom.xml for image
-----------------
```

this is our pom.xml for image

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

actually what is the error as a result i can not insert my file in database please help me

Comment: Can you track your ProductName is visible ? to fixed this you need to check your productName column is not null

Comment: The question is: Why don't you validate your form before you post it to ?   because when you validate all fields you can make sure your data is not missing and your business logic base on each field you want can work like your expect

Comment: The error is pretty clear, that field doesn't allow NULLs in the table.  So you should try and fix that first.

Comment: how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The product you are saving has as null value of PRODUCTNAME attribute. make sure it's not null before you make a call for the function `saveOrUpdate` **OR** remove the **not null** constraint from the table in your database.

Comment: Or from the entity declaration, since you are using h2 i deduce it's possible it's being autogenerated

Comment: so how could i solve this problem?

Comment: change your addProduct method with something like this if(product.getName() != null){ session.saveOrUpdate(product); }

Comment: no it is working but  i can not add dataabase

Comment: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column? what was reason this error happend?